# Display custom popover on standard fields

Tags: lightning-aura-components, popover

I was wondering if there is a way to display a custom pop-over on the hover of a standard field in Salesforce lightning! I know with the overlay library one can display it on custom button clicks or hovers.

To be more specific, i wanted to display a custom pop-over on a field in the highlight panel. Any inputs on this is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.